# Error with adding JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added JQuery to my HTML file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then I add a link to my JavaScript file:

```
<script src="public/javascripts/new_javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(I checked that this link work.)

In the file I do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("hey!");
});
```

But the Google Chrome developer tool shows an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'
```

How can it be an error?

I'm doing this in Rails, and the HTML is like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="public/javascripts/prototype.js?1349898477" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="public/javascripts/effects.js?1349898477" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="public/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1349898477" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="public/javascripts/controls.js?1349898477" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="public/javascripts/rails.js?1349898477" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="public/javascripts/application.js?1349898477" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="public/javascripts/new_javascript.js?1351137775" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have any other script tags on your page?

Comment: This error is specific to jQuery not being loaded. Can you confirm jQuery is being included in your HTML BEFORE your script file? Can you give us an example of your HTML?

Comment: Are you also using Prototype?

Comment: Prototype is overwriting the `$` function used by jQuery.  Why do you have them both?

Comment: Try `jQuery` instead of `$` (because Prototype has overwritten `$`).

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oh, what does Prototype do? I didn't even know about it. It was included for me by default.

Comment: ianpgall and RocketHazmat are correct. Read jQuery's noConflict documentation for more infortmation on how to include other JS libraries with jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: I think jquery IS loading or else you would be getting a ''$ is undefined' error. This might sound like a dumb question but I notice there's no <html> tag in your example. Is it really missing? That could explain why there's no document object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery and Prototype conflict with each other.  Try using jQuery instead of $ for jquery commands:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   alert("hey!");
});
```

Comment: More options are described at: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

If prototype *still* overwrites $ like it's the dark ages, wrap your JQ code in a function like so:

```
(function($) {

    // Do whatever you like with $

    $(function() {
        alert("Document ready");
    })

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```